# Angular Select DropDown not showing selected name during start

Tags: angularjs

Dropdown is not getting highlighted in IE10, it shows empty select box, once clicked,  it displays the name.

It's working fine on all other browsers including IE11.

If i remove data-ng-bind and assign name old way, everything works fine. but not with data-ng-bind.

```
this.setting = {
       drop:'first';
    }
    <select data-ng-model="ctrl.setting.drop" data-ng-change="ctrl.logic()">
                <option value="first" data-ng-bind="'Name1'"></option>
                                       <option value="second" data-ng-bind="'Name2'"></option>
                                     </select>
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: What you want to do ? What a reason to use data-ng-bind ?

Comment: Internationalization